# Test applications for Google Cloud and Azure locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, docker, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to test applications for Google Cloud or Azure **locally** in a computer, similar to the [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) Docker image for AWS?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Can list the services your using?

Comment: I mean the Google Cloud and Azure services in general, or some of them at least. I haven't developed any application yet, but I wanted to know, for future applications I might develop, if I have the possibility of testing locally. For example, with LocalStack, it's possible to test the S3 and Lambda services, among others.

Comment: So yes, some services are can be run locally or have emulators that you can use.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know please any tool, Docker image, etc., for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test you application locally you can use [Google App Engine Local Devolopment server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) to simulate your app running on app engine externally.

[Demo python application via app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app)

As you mentioned docker you may want to test your images locally you can also do this by following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The GCP Buildpacks (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks) can also be used to run applications locally with Docker as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this post. Here are some useful links, you will find

https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/gcloud/